# How to import Qml plugins lib into another project?

Tags: qt, qml, qmake

I have a 2 qml files in a lib and I want to export those to another project and was unable to import in my QuickQmlTest project. I want to use those qml files from QmlPlugin lib in QuickQmlTest project. Is there any additional step I need to do ?   I have a folder structure

```
  QMLProject  
  |-- QmlPlugin -(it is lib)
      |--QML  
         |--CustomButton.qml
         |-- CustomPolygon.qml
  |-- QuickQmlTest - (app)
```

My QmPlugins.pro looks like this

```
TEMPLATE = lib
TARGET = QmlPlugin
QT += qml quick
CONFIG += plugin c++11

TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)


HEADERS += \
    MyPlugin.h

DISTFILES = qmldir \  
    CustomButton.qml \
    CustomPolygon.qml
DESTDIR = $$PWD/lib
```

And I linked the generated dlls into to the QuickQmlTest.pro using

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../QmlPlugin/lib -lQmlPlugin  
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../QmlPlugin
```

MyPlugin.h

```
    #include <QQmlExtensionPlugin>
    #include <QtQml/qqml.h>
    class MyItemModel: public QObject
    {
       Q_OBJECT
       Q_PROPERTY(qreal roundingRadius READ roundingRadius WRITE setRoundingRadius)
        public:
        void setRoundingRadius(const qreal rounding)
        {
            roundingRadius_ = rounding;
        }
         qreal roundingRadius() const
         {
             return roundingRadius_;
         }
         private:
         qreal roundingRadius_{8.0};
    };
    class MyPlugin : public QQmlExtensionPlugin
    {
        Q_OBJECT
        Q_PLUGIN_METADATA(IID QQmlExtensionInterface_iid)
        public:
        void registerTypes(const char* uri)override
        {
            Q_ASSERT(uri == QLatin1String("Components"));
            qmlRegisterType<MyItemModel>(uri, 1, 0, "MyItemModel");
        }
    };
```

in qmldir I have

```
module Components
Components 1.0 CustomButton.qml CustomPolygon.qml
plugin QmlPlugin
```

In the QuickQmlTest (app)
I want to use CustomButton.qml and CustomPolygon.qml in my main.qml
So my main.qml in QuickQmlTest app

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import Components 1.0 //To import the dll from lib 
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    CustomPolygon
    {
     width:60
     height:30  
    }
    CustomButton
    {
     width:60
     height:30  
    }
}
```

And also I want to see my Custom qml types(CustomButton and CustomPolygon) in Quick Design mode which I am unable to achieve.

Comment: show your MyPlugin,h

Comment: added .h details in the description

Comment: The easiest way to return custom component from a plugin is to use some factory method ie. you pass name of the component and receive QQuickItem-derived class. Btw, if you call in your app to regusterTypes the component should be visible in the QML code.

Comment: @folibis Could you show an example how to achieve this ?

Comment: That depends on what you want to archive. Show the code where you instantiate the plugin.

Comment: I updated the description to include my QuickQmlTest . I am not sure if I need to copy the qml plugins dll to some Qt directory to see the plugins .